# Can a graph representation has the same edge twice?

Tags: graph-theory

This is a really simple question, but I couldn't find anything on it. To my understanding, in graphs, there can be multiple edges between two vertices. So when I represent them using an adjacency list or matrix, should I allow the same edge to be represented twice?
like this,

- 1 => 2 4 5 5
- 2 => 4 5 3
- 3 => 1 4 4
- 4 => 5 2 1
- 5 =>

edited:- I'm currently following a CS degree and we were asked to implement a graph using C++. We are required to provide the functionality to add/remove vertices, add edges. I managed to do it but still not sure if should allow the user to insert duplicate edges or print an error when the user tries to insert an edge that already exists.

Comment: "graph" is a somewhat ambiguous term. It might mean "directed" or "undirected" graph; it might or might not allow self-loops (an edge between a vertex and itself); it might or might not allow multiple edges between the same two nodes. Any serious paper about graph will begin by a definition of what precisely is called "graph" throughout the paper. Any graph library for programming languages will either focus on one convention, or allow for different convention through optional parameters to the functions provided.

Answer (score 3):

Addendum - I might have misunderstood, did you mean is it okay for the representation of edges that cannot be duplicated to be redundant, or did you mean is it okay for an edge to occur twice?

In the former case, the question is about how difficult it, in your specific context, is to do the operations on the data structure.

In the latter case: the precise definition of graph varies a bit from source to source. The purest mathematical definition is a set of ordered pairs. Set. So, that means no duplicates. However, in many programming applications (and in other mathematical contexts) it is valid for an edge to exist twice, or an indefinite number of times. So, the real answer to this question is a combination of semantics (of the word "graph" versus "network" etc) and in particular, speaking about software - what is your application?

Comment: Thanks for the knowledge, I really appreciate it, I'm currently following a cs degree and we were asked to implement a directed and an undirected graph using any programming language as an assignment. I managed to implement using c++. But I'm not sure if I should allow the insertion of duplicate edges or print an error when the user tries to insert an edge that already exists.

Comment: @Nethrenial. speaking as an ex cs lecturer at Massey 20 years ago, if I had given such an assignment I would have considered that putting the same edge in a second time should have no effect. I think that is a good default. But, in your position, I would check with the lecturer if the assignment specification is ambiguous.

Comment: Thank you so much, Sir!, I really appreciate it. I'll check with our lecturer.

Comment: According to whom is that *"the purest mathematical definition"*? I've seen plenty of more-or-less-equivalent definitions, and I don't think any was purer than any other.

Comment: @Stef depending on the person asked - any mathematics conducted for the sake of the mathematics without application would be pure. What I meant was something closer to -- the simplest set theoretic definition. But, I was not trying to make any deep point there.